# ST_ClusterKMeans max radius parameter not working as expected

Tags: postgis, clustering

I am trying to make clusters of maximum 20 buildings. Here is my code so far:

```
with data as(
select at2."name" as area_type, a.name,bf.* from building_footprints bf
left join area a on bf."areaID" = a."ID"
left join area_type at2 on at2."ID" = a."areaTypeID"
where a."ID" in (select "areaID" from campaign_scope)
and at2."name"='Uc'
and a.name='test'
)
,
kmeans as(
select "area_type", "name",
"ID",
"geoJson" ,
ST_ClusterKMeans(st_transform(data."geoJson",24313), (select (count(*)/20)::integer from data),50 ) OVER (order by data."ID") AS cluster_id
FROM data
)

,
finalset as (
select * from kmeans

)

select cluster_id, count(*) as bfp_count from finalset  
group by 1
order by bfp_count desc
```

This gives a result set which consists of clusters with more than 10 buildings as well (up to 23). How is this even possible since I have put a limit of 50 m radius for a Kmeans cluster?!